# sorting array of objects alphabetically on selecting options from dropdown in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying ro sort according to Title and Director but only second option from dropdown  works always. Here is my code below. On selecting only  second option that may be either asc or desc the sorting is performed

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: data.movies, sort_term: '',
    };
    this.onSorting = this.onSorting.bind(this);
  }
  onSorting(e) {
    let term = 'Title';
    let option = e.target.value;
    let sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
  return (option == 'asc' ? (a[term] <= b[term] ? -1 : 1) :
    (a[term] >= b[term] ? -1 : 1))
});
    this.setState({ sort_term: term });
    this.setState({ movies: sortedList });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello sort_term={this.state.sort_term}
          onSorting={this.onSorting} />
        <br />
        <Table movies={this.state.movies} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Hello.js**

```
class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    const { sort_term, onSorting } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="header">
        Database
        <ul className="navLeft">
          <li >
            <form >
              <select value={sort_term}
                onChange={onSorting}
                className="searchBar">
                <option value="desc">Sort Title(Z - A)</option>
                <option value="asc">Sort Title(A - Z)</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to define "OnSorting" function like this

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            movies: data.movies,
            sort_term: '',
        };
    }

    onSorting = (e) => {
        let term = 'Title';
        let option = e.target.value;
        let sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
        return (option == 'asc_Title' ? (a[term] >= b[term] ? -1 : 1) :
            (a[term] <= b[term] ? -1 : 1))
        });
        this.setState({ sort_term: term });
        this.setState({ movies: sortedList });
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Hello sort_term={this.state.sort_term}
            onSorting={this.onSorting} />
            <br />
            <Table movies={this.state.movies} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

// Hello.js

```
class Hello extends Component {
    render() {
        const { sort_term, onSorting } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="header">
            Database
            <ul className="navLeft">
                <li >
                <form >
                    <select
                    onChange={onSorting}
                    className="searchBar">
                    <option value="desc">Sort Title(Z - A)</option>
                    <option value="asc">Sort Title(A - Z)</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i made few changes  let sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
      return (option == 'asc' ? (a[term] <= b[term] ? -1 : 1) :
        (a[term] >= b[term] ? -1 : 1))
    });

Comment: Are you using state "sort_term" anywhere else. `this.setState({ sort_term: term });` seems unnecessary.

Comment: I removed this.setState({ sort_term: term }); and  added onChange={(e) => {
                        onSorting(e);
                    }}

Comment: Still it only performs asc i.e second option only

Comment: Also you have values "desc" and "asc" in selectbox. But you are checking for "asc_Title" in "onSorting" function

Comment: I just updated my answer . . its working now. Had to remove `value={sort_term}`

Comment: Ya now its working . As we used  let term = 'Title';